# MySQL complex SQL query requires 2 columns to provide SUM totals based on value of another column (if=Yes) while grouped together

Tags: mysql, select, sum, subquery, inner-join

Hopefully the Title has not scared everyone away, as I was not sure how to word this.

I am trying to figure out a MySQL query that can parse this table of information above and provide an output as follows :

```
sID | ID | Opt1 Total | Opt2 Total
```

Opt1 Total = would only be SUM'd if Opt1=Yes
Opt2 Total = would only be SUM'd if Opt2=Yes

And it needs to be grouped by the ID column.

```
+--------------+--------+------------+------+------------+-----------+
| sID          | amount | status     | Opt1 | Opt2   | ID        |
+--------------+--------+------------+------+------------+-----------+
| 101241103181 |  61.75 | Successful | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101241103181 |  51.50 | Successful | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101241103181 |  77.90 | Successful | No   | Yes        | 21665870  |
| 101241103181 |  71.50 | Successful | No   | Yes        | 21665870  |
| 101241103181 | 111.14 | Successful | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101130103181 | 126.14 | Failed     | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101130103181 | 111.37 | Successful | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101130103181 |  40.25 | Successful | Yes  | No         | 21665870  |
| 101130103181 | 118.50 | Successful | No   | No         | 21665870  |
| 101110103181 |  43.62 | Successful | Yes  | No         | 21665870  |
| 101241103181 |  69.22 | Successful | No   | No         | 40170467  |
| 101241103181 | 128.88 | Successful | No   | No         | 40170467  |
| 101276103181 |  92.27 | Successful | Yes  | No         | 40170467  |
| 101276103181 |  92.27 | Successful | Yes  | No         | 40170467  |
| 101241103181 | 217.36 | Successful | No   | No         | 40170467  |
| 101241103181 |  40.69 | Successful | No   | No         | 40170467  |
| 101241103181 |  82.68 | Successful | No   | No         | 40170467  |
```

I cannot for the life of me work out a query to get this working yet, without doing multiple selects repeatedly for each
bit of information. This table will be 100,000 records long in no time so that is not really adequate.

Hoping someone can assist who has better knowledge with MySQL than I do.

Comment: Yes. Provide DDLs and/or a sqlfiddle AND the desired result set. And yes, the title IS scary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT sID,
       ID,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN Opt1 = 'Yes' THEN Amount
             ELSE 0
           end) AS Opt1Total,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN Opt2 = 'Yes' THEN Amount
             ELSE 0
           end) AS Opt2Total
FROM   yourTable
GROUP  BY sID,
          ID
```

Or only `GROUP BY ID` if you want only one row per ID (but you'll lose some sID information).

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0a18/4) that shows both outputs. Difference on decimals is due to [floating point precision issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: This is almost exactly what I just came up with !! I did not know about the ELSE 0 which you have used, and that removes any NULL values.

I've also incorporated a count on each opt column. This is what I ended up with :

`
select sID,ID,count(CASE WHEN Opt1='Yes' THEN Opt1 END) as Opt1count, sum(CASE WHEN Opt1='Yes' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Opt1,sum(CASE WHEN Opt2='Yes' THEN amount END) as Opt2,sum(CASE WHEN Opt1='No' AND Opt2='No' THEN amount END) as Amount FROM DBTABLE GROUP BY sID,ID ORDER BY sID,ID;
`

Comment: Makes sense, as it is probably the simplest way of getting this output.